# android - SMS Receive Broadcast receiver getting aborted

Tags: android, broadcast

I am developing an android SMS app which will not save the message in the inbox.
I need to verify the content of the message using a webservice call and then remove the broadcast.

In the onReceive() for SMSReceiver

```
 if (messageBody.equals("somedata"))
    {

         Intent i  = new Intent(context,Webservice.class);//webservice validation
         i.putExtra("messageBody",messageBody)
         startService(i);  

    // Stop it being passed to the main Messaging inbox
         abortBroadcast();
    }
```

The Intentservice for webservice call never gets executed.The receiver is aborted before this.
I am new to android,so please let me know if it right to do the webservice call in an intent service started in the onReceive() of the broacast receiver(SMS_RECEIVE).

Comment: have you given reading permission in your androidmainfest.xml file ?

Comment: yes i have given the following permissions <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use logging to be sure that the equals() returns true. If that is the case, it might be that you're doing something time consuming in the onReceive() and the BroadcastReceiver gets killed. From documentation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive(android.content.Context, android.content.Intent)

> The function is normally called within the main thread of its process, so you should never perform long-running operations in it (there is a timeout of 10 seconds that the system allows before considering the receiver to be blocked and a candidate to be killed).

Answer (score 0):

It may be spaces problem in your messageBody variable,

please try this,

```
if (messageBody.trim().equals("somedata"))
```